# smarter way of reading from a .txt file (for-loop?)

Tags: python, file, for-loop, operating-system

I'm reading from a .txt file that has one line of text (`YPerson18`) I'm wondering if there is a smarter way of writing this code preferably using a for loop.

```
import os

parent_dir = "../dirfiles"
os.chdir(parent_dir)

file_name = "userdata.txt"
append_mode = "a"
read_mode = "r"

read_file = open(file_name, read_mode)

the_lines = read_file.read(1)
print("Initial of the first name is: {}".format(the_lines))

the_lines = read_file.read(6)
print("The last name is: {}".format(the_lines))

the_lines = read_file.read(8)
print("The age is: {}".format(the_lines))

read_file.close()
```

How the output should look like:

```
Initial of the first name is: Y
The last name is: Person
The age is: 18
```

Comment: If it only has one line, why would you need a loop?

Comment: why not csv module?

Comment: @mad_: The input isn't comma-separated, or anything-separated at all.

Comment: Read the line and split it using regular expressions.

Comment: @user2357112 we can still specify which delimiter to use. Although I think a simple read would be enough in this case and (if there are multiple rows) loop through it

Comment: @mad_: There is no delimiter. Any delimiter you specify would be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the whole file into a string variable, then use slice notation to get parts of it.

```
with read_file = open(file_name, read_mode):
    line = read_file.read().strip()
    initial = line[0]
    last_name = line[1:7]
    age = int(line[7:])
```